# Ruby: why rescue block value instead of ensure block?

Tags: ruby, exception

As a rule in Ruby method returns value of last executed block, just like this:

```
def boom
    if false
        "a"
    else
        "double a"
    end
end

p boom # "double a"
```

But when I create such compound that comprises `rescue` and `ensure`. The `ensure` is the last block for execution, but the value from `rescue` block is returned. Why it happens?

```
def a
    1.some_weird_method
    "Boom"
rescue NoMethodError
    p "An Error: " + $!.message
ensure
    p "This  value must be returned"
end

p "Why do rescue block returns?:" + a
p RUBY_VERSION
```

the output is:

```
Finished in 44 ms
"An Error: undefined method `some_weird_method' for 1:Integer"
"This  value must be returned"
"Why do rescue block returns?:An Error: undefined method `some_weird_method' for 1:Integer"
"2.4.6"
```

code could be tested here: https://leetcode.com/playground/2NPL8QgN

Comment: Because that's how Ruby is implemented (and I'd argue it makes more sense this way). `ensure` runs no matter what, success or failure, so you'd end up potentially eating what you really care about.

Comment: (Noting that if you're returning a reference to something you could still modify whatever is being referenced, although I wouldn't as this would lead to some cognitive overhead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ensure` by default doesn't change the return value. You can bypass that by calling `return` explicitly inside `ensure` I haven't seen that pattern too often (if ever) though.

http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2009/11/17/ensure-with-explicit-return.html